# Render a string only on first iteration of a loop

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

Is there a way to append ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse" only the first time the loop gets there? I tried, bool and a counter, but it obviously it gets initialized every single time, i tried a goto to skip the incrementation, but this way it doesn't even initialize it :)

**I'm trying to get the following HTML code:**

```
<li class="">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i>First Level<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level background-white collapse">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Second Level1</a>
            <ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Second Level2</a>
            <ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</li>
```

**This is my C# code:**

```
private static string RenderMenuRecursive(ItemMenu menu, int level)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (level > 0)
    {
        int firstIteration = 0; // This will be initialized as 0 every time :\

        if (level == 1)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<li class=\"\"><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-fw\"></i>"+ menu.name + "<span class=\"fa arrow\"></span></a>");
        }
        if (level == 2)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<ul class=\"nav nav-second-level background-white collapse\"><li><a href=\"#\">" + menu.name + "</a>");
        }
        if (level == 3)
        {
            if (firstIteration == 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<ul class=\"" + "nav nav-third-level background-white collapse" + "\">");
                firstIteration++;
            }

            sb.AppendLine("<li><a href=\"#\">" + menu.name + "</a></li>");
        }

    }

    level++;

    foreach (ItemMenu subMenu in menu.subMenuItems)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(RenderMenuRecursive(subMenu, level));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**This is what I actually get:**

```
<li class=""><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i>First Level<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="nav nav-second-level background-white collapse"><li><a href="#">Second Level1</a>
<ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
<li><a href="#">Third Level1</a></li>

<ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
<li><a href="#">Third Level2</a></li>

<ul class="nav nav-second-level background-white collapse"><li><a href="#">Second Level2</a>
<ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
<li><a href="#">Third Level3</a></li>

<ul class="nav nav-third-level background-white collapse">
<li><a href="#">Third Level4</a></li>
```

Comment: So the problem is with the indentation?

Comment: @MotiAzu , nope, i can't manage to get the expected code

Comment: Why aren't you closing the `ul`s & `li`s?

Comment: sorry, I tried to understand your question and compare the code snippets, but did not manage to get it. Can you simplify your code to the core part and state what exactly is wrong with your "actual" versus your wanted version?

Comment: oh, got it. You get too many "<ul>" tags in the third level, right?

Comment: @JNF, i've just updated the li's

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just use a partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define and initialize the variable in the wrong place. Since you call your method for every iteration, your variable gets a new scope and is initialized in every iteration, too.

If you want to call the method within your for-each loop, you will need to let the method know what iteration you're in. For example by introducing a parameter:

```
private static string RenderMenuRecursive(ItemMenu menu, int level, bool firstIteration)
{
    [...]

        if (level == 3)
        {
            if (firstIteration)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<ul class=\"" + "nav nav-third-level background-white collapse" + "\">");
                firstIteration++;
            }

            sb.AppendLine("<li><a href=\"#\">" + menu.name + "</a>");
        }

    [...]

    var firstIteration = true;

    foreach (ItemMenu subMenu in menu.subMenuItems)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(RenderMenuRecursive(subMenu, level, firstIteration));
        firstIteration = false;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Needs to be stated though that this issue is not related to rendering, StringBuilders, HTML or MVC at all. It is simply an issue of how to work with nested (recursive) method calls and state...

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on **int firstIteration = 0;**
It will always set to 0 as it is not static member (You should avoid static members anyway)

You should add param to Your method RenderMenuRecursive(subMenu, level, **renderUl**) and move

**int firstIteration = 0; // This will be initialized as 0 every time**

to

```
int firstIteration = 0;

foreach (ItemMenu subMenu in menu.subMenuItems)
{
    sb.AppendLine(RenderMenuRecursive(subMenu, level, firstInteration == 0));

    firstIteration++; 
}
```

Also consider method name change cause there is no recursive call.